# Convert apache environment variables to lowercase

Tags: apache

I have an environment variable (set from HTTP headers) that could be both upper or lower case.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Accept-Language "^([a-z][a-z])(-[a-z][a-z])*" LANGUAGE=$1 COUNTRY=$2
```

How do I convert the COUNTRY variable to lower case in apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the apache built-in [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) function "tolower". You'll have to define it in either your server or vhost config:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then you can use it by `${lc:}` in a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANGUAGE:${lc:%{ENV:LANGUAGE}},E=COUNTRY:${lc:%{ENV:COUNTRY}},L]

# (Or just the "COUNTRY")
RewriteRule ^ - [E=COUNTRY:${lc:%{ENV:COUNTRY}},L]
```

The rules themselves could be in an htaccess file.

Comment: Can't I add the rules in the vhost file?

Comment: Just tested it out and I am able to put this rule in the vhost file. I had to make some changes. Used the COUNTRY variable instead of M and Removed the Last flag so that more rules are processed that actually make use of the lowercase COUNTRY var. `RewriteRule ^ - [E=COUNTRY:${lc:%{ENV:COUNTRY}}]`   Do you see any problems with this?

Comment: @pkrish No that looks fine, changed answer to replace the "M"s (they weren't supposed to be there). The "L" flag isn't needed, just need to make sure your rules don't loop. The above ones won't.

Comment: Thanks! What is the purpose of the - in the RewriteRule? I couldn't find that in the docs.

Comment: @pkrish the `-` is a "pass through", just means don't change the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simpler solution:

```
RequestHeader set country "expr=%{tolower:%{env:COUNTRY}}"
```

This creates a request header "country" that is the lowercase version of the COUNTRY environment variable.

If you start from an http header and you want to create its lowercase counterpart, you can use the `req` function instead:

```
RequestHeader set country "expr=%{tolower:%{req:COUNTRY}}"
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#functions.